# wordpress previous next navigation not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

**Previous** and **Next** pagination in my latest WordPress theme that I'm working on is not working correct...

For example:
I have 5 posts and I have set Blog Pages Show at Most in reading settings to 2 posts...
This works fine in index and it shows 2 posts every page...but in my `author.php` that I have set my loop to show 12 posts per page, I cannot see my pagination??
I can see my 5 Posts, but I can still navigate between 3 pages through my navigation and every page shows the same 5 posts....This happens in my `archive.php` too...

How can I change my Pagination function that works apart from reading settings and shows the pagination buttons whether the posts are more than the number I have set in loop?

Here is my pagination function in my `functions.php`:

```
function infinite_pagination() {
    $prev_link = get_previous_posts_link('<span id="newer"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><div>newer posts</div></span>');
    $next_link = get_next_posts_link('<span id="older"><div>older posts</div><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>');
    if ($prev_link || $next_link) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
        echo '<section class="pagination">';
        if ( $prev_link ){
            echo $prev_link;
        }
        if ($next_link){
            echo $next_link;
            }
        echo '</section>';
    echo '</div>';
    }   
}
```

and here is my loop for `author.php` :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $post_query = new WP_Query ( 'posts_per_page=12'  );
    if($post_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while($post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>
              <-- Content -->           
        <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php infinite_pagination(); ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I broke your question out a bit better. Don't open your question with an apology either. just ask :)

Comment: I think it is not working because you are not dealing with the main query here, but your own custom query. Have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops to see how to deal with pagination in such cases.

Comment: … or, alternatively, you can make this a little easier by using the main query – and specifying a `pre_get_posts` filter that modifies the query for your author page to use a different `posts_per_page` value than the default. Have a look at the example here, https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type

Comment: Thank you so much @CBroe ...It's Solved now.